# Ubuntu 17.10 how to replace default dock with Plank or Cairo

Tags: 17.10, dock, plank

I was wondering how I can replace the default dock with an alternative like plank or cairo? I installed plank and launched it but that does nothing. How do I actually switch to the newly installed dock now?

Comment: I do not think either of those work with wayland. You can try an x session.

Comment: cairo seems to have support since 2014 http://glx-dock.org/mr_article.php?b=5&a=73

Comment: I can not tell the version from ubuntu packaging and do not have the interest to look. Install it and run it and tell us how it goes. Simply stating that it does not work is insufficient information we need a error message or something. For example, do you know why my red car will not start? I turn the key , but nothing happens.

Comment: Well if I were able to debug this issue myself, surely I wouldn't ask here. I do not know how docks work in Gnome.

Comment: OK, well good luck to you then. I did not ask you to debug the issue yourself, but rather to provide additional information so we could help debug it for you. I suppose your other option would be to file a bug report.

Comment: What information other than the version of the package can I provide and also how do I get the information needed?

Comment: First, generally here, one question per "Question" . Are you using plank or cairo or glx-doc ? Choose one. Then identify the version. Then run it from the command line and report any errors. The link you gave is from 2014, which is ancient in terms of wayland.Does it work in an X session ? See https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html

Comment: See also https://bugs.launchpad.net/cairo-dock-core/+bug/1722503 so again I tend to think it is not going to work well, if at all, on wayland.

Comment: glx-dock and cairo seem to be synonymous but yea it looks I will just have to revert to ubuntu-xsession.